# How can I concat Dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

hello

I make DataFrame like this:

```
index_date=pd.date_range('1/1/2000','31/12/2000', freq='H')
```

`data=random.sample(range(8761),8761 )`

`df= pd.DataFrame(data, index=index_date)`

I need to make the sum per month, but my code below doesn't works !

`pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(sum(df['con'][df.index.month==i])) for i in range(1,13,1)])`

return error message

```
ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!
```

But if I change in "series" it works ! Why ?

```
pd.concat([pd.Series(sum(df['con'][df.index.month==i])) for i in range(1,13,1)])
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will groupby each month.

```
df.groupby(df.index.month).sum()
```

Comment: OK, but  January 2016 isn't différent than juanary 2017 . I need 12 rows, (one per month).

Comment: Do you have an idea?

Comment: I changed my answer.

Comment: Great, I was thinking about using groupby but I am not strong enough in python. Thank you.